# How to get url value and compare with input value when using cypress in react project?

Tags: cypress

how can i get url value param in cypress when I using react and then compare if there are the same value in input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Cypress commands return promise-like objects, so a solution could be:

```
cy.url().then( url => {
  cy.get(inputField).should('have.value',url)
}
```

Comment: maybe you know how I can change the url by adding parameters to it via? for fields?

Comment: http://localhost:28080/app/form/54fd3434f?text_field=Text&text_field2=Text2

Comment: cy.url() gets the current url. If you would like to change the url, aka visit another page, then use cy.visit('localhost:28080/app/form/')

alternatively, if this is the url all your tests depends on, then use 
cypress.json
{
baseurl: 'localhost:28080/app/form/'
}
then cy.visit('/')